# Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'data_Events' because it is not full-text indexed

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

При попытке вложить параметр в хранимую процедуру получаю

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'data_Events' because it is not full-text indexed
```

Вкладываю таким образом

```
 String query ="{call "+QUERY_GET_EVENTS+"(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    stmt.setInt(1,0);
                    stmt.setDate(2,null);
                    stmt.setDate(3,null);
                    stmt.setInt(4,0);
                    stmt.setString(5,"");
                    stmt.setByte(6, (byte) 0);
                    stmt.setLong(7,0);
                    stmt.setLong(8,0);
```

Типы входных параметров:

```
            [dbo].[sql_GetEvents]
             @stream int = null
           , @dateFrom datetime = null
           , @dateTo datetime = null
           , @user int = null
           , @text nvarchar(max) = null
           , @super bit = null
           , @markInFrom bigint = null
           , @markInTo bigint = null
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вы используете предикаты полнотекстового поиска, а полнотекстовый индекс не создан.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема в базе?

Comment: Не столько в базе, сколько в отсутствии полнотекстового индекса, который, вообще говоря, не в базе хранится.